# MySQL Spatial Within function gives errors

Tags: mysql, spatial

I have a table of areas which has an AREA_ID column and an AREA column which is a Polygon type.

I am running the following query but I cannot seem to get it to work:

```
SELECT AREA_ID, AsText(AREA) 
FROM networkmodel.sit_area 
WHERE Within(AREA, Polygon((
50.913424 -1.420527, 
50.915805 -1.391516, 
50.898053 -1.390142, 
50.895021 -1.428251, 
50.913424 -1.420527)))
```

This query gives me an "Operand should contain 1 column" error.

If I put one less set of brackets around my coordinates I get an "Illegal non geometric '(50.913424 -1.420527)' value found during parsing" error instead. Are my coordinates the  wrong format?

I am aware from the MySQL documentation that the Within function has not been implemented properly and falls back to the MBR implementation instead but I am just testing it out at the moment. I have used the Contains function in the past with success to return me records in a similar way by using a Point as the second parameter instead of a polygon and this is supposed to be the opposite of that.

It is my understanding from the documentation that this function takes two parameters and checks whether the first (my areas column in this case) falls within the given Polygon.

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right I made it work now, Instead of using this function I had to change the Polygon declaration to:

```
GeomFromText('Polygon((50.913424 -1.420527, 50.915805 -1.391516, 50.898053 -1.390142, 50.895021 -1.428251, 50.913424 -1.420527))')
```